# leer ficheros Java

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos, jframe, filewriter

Tengo un conjunto de archivos txt con 4 colores en codigo RGB (rojo,verde,azul), cada archivo contiene los colores rgb separados por espacios y el nombre del color: “84 84 84 gris” en cada linea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La aplicación la estoy desarrollando en java con interfaz grafica (JFrame) contiene un panel que deberá cambiar de color de fondo y un label con el     nombre del color visualizado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El panel cambia de color por medio de un recurso compartido para los hilos, una clase en java que contendrá 3 variables enteras correspondientes a cada color rgb respectivamente y una variable cadena de texto correspondiente al     nombre, dicha clase sera accedida por los hilos en ejecución por medio de métodos que cambian el valor de los colores RGB y el nombre del color e inmediatamente la informacion del panel es actualizada (color fondo panel, nombre color).

El problema es que necesito leer el archivo **colores1.txt** cada linea que esta en el archivo me representa un color en RGB y segun lo que diga en cada linea me debería mostrar en el panel el color con el nombre correspondiente

Este es mi codigo

```
    public class Hilo implements Runnable{
        
        RGBColor color;
        int rojo;
        int verde;
        int azul;
        String nombre;
        int rojo2;
        int verde2;
        int azul2;
        String nombre2;
    
        public Hilo(RGBColor color, int rojo, int verde, int azul,String nombre, int rojo2, int verde2, int azul2,String nombre2) {
            this.color = color;
            this.rojo = rojo;
            this.verde = verde;
            this.azul = azul;
            this.rojo2 = rojo2;
            this.verde2 = verde2;
            this.azul2 = azul2;
            this.nombre=nombre;
            this.nombre2=nombre2;
        }
        
    FileReader entrada = null;

String linea = "";

String directorio  =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cual es la ubicacion del 
archivo");
String sDirectorio = directorio;
File f = new File(sDirectorio);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(entrada);
    
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            this.color.set(rojo,verde,azul,nombre);
            
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
            this.color.set(rojo2,verde2,azul2,nombre2);
        }
        
    }

    public class RGBColor{
    
        private int rojo;
        private int verde;
        private int azul;
        private String nombre;
        private JPanel jpanel;
        private JLabel label;
    
    
    
    
        public synchronized void set(int rojo,
                int verde,
                int azul,
                String nombre) {


        this.rojo = rojo;
        this.verde = verde;
        this.azul = azul;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        jpanel.setBackground(new Color(rojo,verde,azul));
        label.setText(nombre);

}
    
        /**
         * @param jpanel the jpanel to set
         */
        public void setJpanel(JPanel jpanel) {
            this.jpanel = jpanel;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param label the label to set
         */
        public void setLabel(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es realmente el problema?

Comment: Necesito implementarle un metodo de sincronizacion pero no se como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si he entendido bien, pero tu región crítica debería de ser esta, por lo que añadiendo synchronized ahí deberías tener el método sincronizado para que dos hilos no puedan acceder simultáneamente al  recurso.

```
public synchronized void set(int rojo,
                int verde,
                int azul,
                String nombre) {


        this.rojo = rojo;
        this.verde = verde;
        this.azul = azul;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        jpanel.setBackground(new Color(rojo,verde,azul));
        label.setText(nombre);

}
```

Lo normal, o al menos por lo que he trabajado con threads en java, es poner el método de sincronización para ello. Para que dos hilos no puedan acceder **simultaneamente** al mismo recurso, ,de ahí que ponga el `synchronized`en el set, por que es desde donde se accede al recurso.